# Java filter NullPointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

Trying to create filter, need to choose records which type is not equals "N". I trying do it by this way, but I getting NullPointer. I think this is because in my database `Type` sometimes is null. How can I fix this filter to not get NullPointer?

```
Collection<Plan> plan = packet.getPlan().stream() //    
            .filter(item -> !item.getType().equals("N")) //
            .map(packetPlan -> Plan.newInstance( //
                    packetPlan, //
                    activePlan.contains(packetPlan.getType()))) //
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "_I think this is because in my database Type sometimes is null._" - correct. "_How can I fix this filter to not get NullPointer_" - add a check for `null` in your `filter()` before getting the type.

Comment: did you try check if object is not null before getting the type?

Comment: What if I need to select those records, which have `Type` null or not equal "N"? Then adding this check is not good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another filter

```
Collection<Plan> plan = packet.getPlan().stream() //    
            .filter(item -> item != null) //
            .filter(item -> !item.getType().equals("N")) //
            .map(packetPlan -> Plan.newInstance( //
                    packetPlan, //
                    activePlan.contains(packetPlan.getType()))) //
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Alternatively: `filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: What if I need to select those records, which have `Type` null or not equal "N"? Then adding this check is not good for me.

Comment: Your filter says you dont. Your filter says t cannot be null. Anyway, it is up to you how you filter your stream.